# Expanding an arthimetic algorithm for a Weightlifting

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math, calculator

So I am a quite novice programmer, I have been teaching myself Ruby for a couple of weeks now, and I made a program that estimates your 1 repetition max possible weight lifting capabilities.

The algorithm I used is:

```
weight = gets.to_i

reps = gets.to_i

x=Rational(reps,30)
x=x.to_f

one_RM = weight*(1+x)
```

Now this has worked well to get an estimate equal to other 1rep max calculators out there, but what I want to do is to make it so that it takes any weight and reps value and lets the user choose which rep range to convert to.

If that was unclear here is an example of what I mean:

user writes 100 kg and 10 reps program prompts the user for a rep value it would like to get an estimate for, eg instead of only 1rm it can predict anything from 1-100rm etc.

here is a series of formulas for how to calculate the 1 rep maximum:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-repetition_maximum#Calculating_1RM

I tried looking trough them and see if I could come up with an idea, but I'm not an expert at math(understatement) and I am very new to programming, so my brain is not contributing any useful solutions, any insights greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compute the 1RM and then invert the formulas you link to using the new value if `r` (the number of repetitions your user *wants to do*).

So with the formula you're using, and `r_asked` and `w_asked` the values for repetitions and weight :

[image: formula]

You now need to do :

`w_asked = one_RM / (1+ r_asked/30)`